# SQL: Create new column with values that isn't in either columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I basically have this table where 22 appears either in A or B:

```
A  |  B
---| ---
22 |  0 
32 |  22
45 |  22 
22 |  5
```

And I want to create a new column from this table that only has the value from the row that isn't 22 e.g.

```
C  
-
0
32
45
5
```

How do I do this?

**edit:**  The table above comes from this statement

```
SELECT A,B FROM table 
WHERE (A = '22' OR B = '22')
```

Comment: Oh I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: You want to create a new column in the actual table or in the result of your select query?

Comment: *Could* a situation arise where both columns contain `22` and if so, what should `C` contain then?

Comment: I want to create a new column in the result only. 22 will only appear mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to generate this output:

```
SELECT CASE a WHEN 22 THEN b ELSE a END AS c
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  22 IN (a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a = 22 AND b=22 THEN 0 WHEN a = 22 and b != 22 THEN b ELSE a END c
FROM #comm
WHERE 22 IN (a,b)
```

If both have 22 then it will return 0 or you can change the value

Comment: That's a good idea to return 0 if both are 22, for my table it is for definite it will only appear in A or B.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A AS C FROM MYTABLE WHERE A != 22
UNION 
SELECT B AS C FROM MYTABLE WHERE B != 22
```

UNION remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will have to add a column C into your table, this is how you do it:

```
 ALTER TABLE YourTableName
 ALTER COLUMN C decimal
```

Afterwards, you retrieve values from columns A,B and insert them into C:

```
 INSERT INTO YourTableName(C)
 SELECT A,B
 FROM YourTableName WHERE A<>22 and B<>22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name
 ALTER COLUMN c INT

UPDATE table_name
SET c= CASE WHEN a<>22 THEN a ELSE b END
```

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this?

```
--drop table ##t1
select * 
into ##t1
from(
select 'a1'c1,'b1'c2 union all
select 'a2'c1,'b2'c2 union all
select 'a3'c1,'b3'c2 union all
select 'a4'c1,'a3'c2 union all
select 'a3'c1,'b4'c2 union all
select 'a5'c1,'b5'c2 
)t


select *,
       case when t2.c1 is null then t1.c1 else t1.c2 end c3
from ##t1 t1
left join
(
    select *
    from
    (
        select distinct c1
        from ##t1
    )t1
    join
    (
        select distinct c2
        from ##t1
    )t2
      on t1.c1=t2.c2
)t2
  on t1.c1=t2.c1
```

this is a generic solution